# xslt include node to for-each-group when group-by node doesn't exist

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have an xml:

```
<ShipmentUnit>
    <TrackingID>101012163322</TrackingID>
    <ShipUnitSequenceID>5</ShipUnitSequenceID>
    <Type>CRDCRT</Type>
    <DocumentReference type="parentUnit">
        <DocumentID>
            <ID>101012163322</ID>
        </DocumentID>
    </DocumentReference>
    <PointOfStagingCode>KRD001000000</PointOfStagingCode>
</ShipmentUnit>
<ShipmentUnit>
    <TrackingID>101012163322</TrackingID>
    <ShipUnitSequenceID>7</ShipUnitSequenceID>
    <Type>CRDCRT</Type>
    <DocumentReference type="parentUnit">
        <DocumentID>
            <ID>101012163322</ID>
        </DocumentID>
    </DocumentReference>
    <PointOfStagingCode>KRD001000000</PointOfStagingCode>
</ShipmentUnit>
<ShipmentUnit>
    <TrackingID>101012163346</TrackingID>
    <ShipUnitSequenceID>9</ShipUnitSequenceID>
    <Type>CRDCRT</Type>
    <PointOfStagingCode>KRD001000000</PointOfStagingCode>
</ShipmentUnit>
```

And I want to make a group:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="ShipmentUnit" group-by="DocumentReference[@type='parentUnit']/DocumentID/ID">
```

The problem is when the XML doesn't have a `group-by` node `for-each-group` ignores that XML node.

How to include node

```
<ShipmentUnit>
    <TrackingID>101012163346</TrackingID>
    <ShipUnitSequenceID>9</ShipUnitSequenceID>
    <Type>CRDCRT</Type>
    <PointOfStagingCode>KRD001000000</PointOfStagingCode>
</ShipmentUnit>
```

to `for-each-group` result anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make sure an non-existing node creates an empty string as the grouping key using `group-by="string(DocumentReference[@type='parentUnit']/DocumentID/ID)"`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
group-by="(DocumentReference[@type='parentUnit']/DocumentID/ID, '*')[1]"
```

The elements with no document ID will then form their own group with a grouping key of "*".

If you want each such document to be in a group of its own, you could use generate-id() in place of '*'.